Configuration Manager 2309 "Specify a valid UNC file path" while creating an application
1When Creating an Application using the wizard, I am getting a "Specify a valid UNC path" dialog after browsing to the files location manually and entering it and attempting to continue to the wizards' next step. Also tried prefacing the file with the \ and running the Configuration Manager as an administrator. Neither resulted in a different outcome. Searching the dialog message has yielded no aid relevant to Microsoft Configuration Manager.
Create Application Wizard with the "Specify a valid UNC filepath error dialog in spite of using a complete filepath

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
